# How to add ical to iphone application

Tags: iphone, tableview, icalendar

I need to add calendar to my tableview . please any one help me how to add ical to my application .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native calendar view in Cocoa Touch.

I've used [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) with very good results.

Comment: i added Kal to my application in appdelegate,the calendar view i can able to view. kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init] if i use view did load of another tableview controller. i cant able view calendar view . why?

Comment: @Rkm - You might consider starting a new question and posting your code. From the line you posted, it's hard to tell what's happening.

Comment: As sample for kal for your answer, i am following, i added library to my application , if i call to  KalViewController in my tableview is not able to see user view of calendar

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Tapku Library](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary), it contains a nice calendar example. Specifically, you will want to look at the `TKCalendar*`.

Comment: when i build Tapku library project getting error for No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).

Comment: Theres a standalone library, and then there is a demo project, make sure you build the library, and then build/run the demo.